# Google Search Console cached my email account

Tags: google-search-console

I have a url that has been indexed by Google for more than 3 years and the title changes from year to year. With a new gmail account or not signed in, you will see the new title, but if you log into the old Gmail account, you will still see the old title (not the new title). I suspect the old gmail account is cached search results.

I tried going into GSC to resend the index request and google re-indexed the url yesterday, but the above situation persists.

Can you help me?

Thanks all!

Comment: I checked, it caches the results by language. If I choose English language, it will have the old title (cached), but if I choose another language, it will have a new title.